# Does ejabberd support audio/video calls?

Tags: xmpp, audio, ejabberd, instant-messaging, video-conferencing

My server is running Ubuntu and I have installed ejabberd as one of the famous xmpp servers in order to organize chatting system. Ejabbered is working fine with text messages, but I would like to know whether it supports audio/video calls or not?

If not, could you please tell me which xmpp server to use for this purpose?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It's not ejabberd what handles audio/video talk. It's handled with Jingle ([XEP-0166](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html)), which is client-to-client protocol extension for XMPP. The clients have to support it.